# Two word boundaries (\b) to isolate a single word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the word that appears immediately after a number - in the sentence below, it is the word "meters".

> The tower is 100 **meters** tall.

Here's the pattern that I tried which didn't work:

### **`\d+\s*(\b.+\b)`**

But this one did:

### **`\d+\s*(\w+)`**

The first incorrect pattern matched this:

> The tower is 100 **meters tall**.

I didn't want the word "tall" to be matched. I expected the following behavior:

**`\d+`**     `match one or more occurrence of a digit`
**`\s*`**    `match any or no spaces`
**`(`**       `start new capturing group`
**`\b`**      `find the word/non-word boundary`
**`.+`**      `match 1 or more of everything except new line`
**`\b`**      `find the next word/non-word boundary`
**`)`**      `stop capturing group`

The problem is I don't know tiddly-twat about regex, and I am very much a  noob as a noob can be. I am practicing by making my own problems and trying to solve them - this is one of them. Why didn't the match stop at the second break `(\b)`?

---

<sub>This is Python flavored

[Here's the regex101 test link of the above regex.](https://regex101.com/r/iJ1xE3/1)</sub>

Comment: You can use: [`\d+\s*(\b.+?\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ1xE3/2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) which covers just about any regex question you could ask.

Comment: Well, you can't use a word boundary `\b` between digits, or between a digit and letter or underscore. Reason is they are all considered words. In your regex the optional `\s*` whitespace is not actually optional according to the engine. Its the only way it would match. Besides that, what composes the _word_ you are trying to match ?

Comment: @Mathletics It is a nice post, but how can anyone manage to use it to troubleshoot their code? It is very lengthy and is just like any other regex-tutorial online - packed with information from a-z (no pun intended).

Comment: @sln "word" as in "word character" (\w), or a collection of it.

Comment: You should require a space between the number and word and use a whitespace boundary before the number and after the word. Ex: `(?<!\S)\d+\s+(\w+)(?!\S)`

Comment: @RenaeLider if one of the below answers were helpful please accept an answer.

Answer (score 8):

It didn't stop because `+` is [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) by default, you want `+?` for a non-greedy match.

A concise explanation — `*` and `+` are greedy quantifiers/operators meaning they will match as much as they can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match.

You need to follow these operators with `?` for a non-greedy match, going in the above order it would be (`*?`) "zero or more" or (`+?`) "one or more" — but preferably "as few as possible".

Also a word boundary `\b` matches positions where one side is a word character (letter, digit or underscore OR a unicode letter, digit or underscore in Python 3) and the other side is not a word character. I wouldn't use `\b` around the `.` if you're unclear what's in between the boundaries.

Comment: I am just stating the chapters regarding greedy and non-greedy quantifiers. I have no idea what those are at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It match both words because `.` match (nearly) all characters, so also space character, and because `+` is greedy, so it will match as much as it could. If you would use `\w` instead of `.` it would work (because `\w` match only word characters - a-zA-Z_0-9).